# Get the full info from the ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a my main array that looks like this:

```
String[] main = new String[products.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < main.Length; i++)
{
    main[i] = products[i].id + 
              products[i].productowner + 
              products[i].description + 
              products[i].countryofmanufacture;
}
```

And a List of strings that has only a few of products[i].productowner values:

```
List<string> specificproductowners  = new List<string>();
```

And i wonder if there is away that by clicking on John i get all the other info from the main array (id, description,ountryofmanufacture)

```
         A Windows Form listBox (specificproductowners)
         -----------------------------
         |        John               |            
         |        Alex               |
         |        Tom                |
         |        Jan                |
         -----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want query *collection* try *Linq*, something like this:

```
List<string> specificproductowners = products
  .Select(product => product.productowner)
  .Distinct()
  // .OrderBy(owner => owner) // Uncomment, if you want to sort 
  .ToList();
```

If you want to add owners to a `ListBox`:

```
MyListBox.Items.AddRange(products
  .Select(product => product.productowner)
  .Distinct()
  // .OrderBy(owner => owner) // Uncomment, if you want to sort
  .ToArray());             // AddRange wants an array
```

**Edit:** If you want to obtain all the items in the `products` filtered by `productowner` you can use another *Linq*:

```
string owner = "Alex";

List<string> filtered = products
  .Where(product => product.productowner == owner) // "Alex" only
  .Select(product => string.Join(", ",  // let's combine into "id, description, country"
     product.id, 
     product.description,
     product.countryofmanufacture))
  .ToList();

 ...
 MessageBox.Show(
     string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filtered), 
   $"Test filtered for product owner \"{owner}\"");
```

Comment: Much nicer way than mine but i meant that i already have the owners in ListBox and i want to get the full info of each of them if  double click on the name

Comment: @Simle: so on product owner (say, Alex) you want to obtain all the items in `products` which have `productowner == "Alex"`?

Comment: Yes by double clicking(or moving the mouse) on alex i get a kind of temporary MessageBox that has all alex info

Comment: @Simle: in this case it seems you just want to filter out the `products` - yet another *Linq* (`Where`)

Comment: My main issue is with clicking on an item in the listbox  because i know how to get the index of the item clicked  but not the value of it and i cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: @Simle: if you have `index` you can easily get corresponding value: `string owner = MyListBox.Items[index].ToString();`